# Powershell command run on CMD with if condition

Tags: powershell, batch-file, bitlocker

Example 1:

```
for /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%A in ('manage-bde -status %systemdrive% ^| findstr "    Encryption Method:"') do (
    if "%%A"=="AES" goto EncryptionCompleted
)
:EncryptionCompleted
```

Example 2:

```
for /F %%A in ('wmic /namespace:\\root\cimv2\security\microsofttpm path win32_tpm get IsEnabled_InitialValue ^| findstr "TRUE"') do (
    if "%%A"=="TRUE" goto nextcheck
)
:nextcheck
```

Please help to find the below code as run on `.bat` to stop script execution.

The command is:

```
powershell.exe (Get-Tpm | Select -Property TpmReady).TpmReady -eq $False

then goto Failed
:Failed
```

Comment: Why don't you use the same `for` syntax you used for the two other lines?

Comment: I would advise you DO NOT use the same logic at all! What do you think will happen in the first example if `manage-bde -status %systemdrive%` returns an error? if `findstr` doesn't match `Encryption` or `Method:`? or `If ` NOT `"%%A"=="AES"`? The script will run the nexy line, i.e. `:EncryptionCompleted`. Now apply the same logic to Example 2:...

Comment: I'm also wondering what is wrong with ```manage-bde -status %SYSTEMDRIVE% -protectionaserrorlevel``` or the shorter ```manage-bde -status %SYSTEMDRIVE% -p``` then use the Error code `0` or `1` to determine if the drive ha been encrypted.

Comment: Also the second example doesn't require a `for` loop at all either, ```wmic /namespace:\\root\cimv2\security\microsofttpm path win32_tpm get IsEnabled_InitialValue 2>NUL | find "TRUE" 1>NUL``` Then use conditionals `&&` and/or `||`, OR use the Error code `0` or `1` from `find` to determine if it is enabled.

Comment: Could you also please [edit] your question, to explain what the specific task is you're trying to perform with your [[tag:powershell]] or [[tag:batch-file]]. This will help us to offer you the more appropriate scripting mechanism(s) for doing so, and the si.plest, most efficient or robust ways of doing so.

Comment: I think it's time to write everything in powershell.

Comment: @js2010, that's only useful if the end user specifically pre-configures the Operating System to allow the PowerShell script to be run!

Comment: @compo `powershell -executionpolicy bypass`.  The default policy is only to prevent accidental execution.

Comment: That's for launching a powershell script from cmd.exe or a batch file @js2010! So where's the benefit in this case for writing it all in PowerShell, if you have to write a batch file to run it anyhow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Since you're only looking to act on a Boolean value, you can communicate that via the PowerShell process' *exit code*, with `0` corresponding to `$true` and `1` to `$false`, given that the widely observed convention is that exit code `0` signals success, whereas any nonzero exit code signals an error condition.

  - Boolean values in PowerShell can directly be converted to integers, which, however, performs the *opposite* mapping: `[int] $true` is `1` and `[int] $false` is `0`.
  - Therefore, the logic must be *reversed* with `-not` before passing the Boolean to PowerShell's `exit` statement.
- On the `cmd.exe` (batch-file) side, this allows you to act on the exit code with the `||` operator, which only executes the RHS in case of *failure*, i.e. if the LHS command reported a *nonzero* exit code (such as `1`).

```bash
powershell.exe -noprofile -c "exit -not (Get-Tpm).TpmReady" || goto :FAILED

echo "TPM is ready."
exit /b 0

:FAILED

echo "TPM is NOT ready." >&2
exit /b 1
```

<sup>Note that I've added the following [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) parameters to the PowerShell call: `-noprofile` to potentially speed up execution, and `-c` (`-Command`) to explicitly signal that a command (piece of PowerShell code) is being passed.</sup>

Comment: Its great, i need only action on if "TPM is not ready" what means for this code ">&2"

Comment: Glad to hear it, @ZaheerAbdullah. `>&2` is a stream redirection that redirects stdout(the default output stream, for data, whose implied number is `1`) to (`&`) stream number `2`, the stderr stream (used for error messages and everything that sin't data, such as status messages).

Answer (score 0):

A demo of doing everything in powershell.

```
(get-bitlockervolume $env:systemdrive).encryptionmethod

None


(get-ciminstance -namespace root\cimv2\security\microsofttpm win32_tpm).
  IsEnabled_InitialValue

True


(get-tpm).TpmReady

True
```